# Requirejs and polyfill.io mishmash

Tags: javascript, requirejs, polyfills

I have a problem adding these two libraries on IE11 and Safari 12.
IE11 and Safari 12 throw an error so I can't use ResizeObserver.
However, separately they work correctly or in reverse order. What could be the problem and how to solve it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=ResizeObserver" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="demo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Source to debug: [https://jsbin.com/yacovakupu/edit?html,js,output](http://jsbin.com/yacovakupu/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

You are using RequireJS and polyfill.io does support AMD, so you need to load it using RequireJS:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="demo"></div>
  <script>
    require(['https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=ResizeObserver'], function (ResizeObserver) {
      console.log(ResizeObserver)

      var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
      demo.innerHTML = ResizeObserver;
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```